# How to get preivous month total count

Tags: vb6

I want to get the previous month total day count

Code

```
Dim period as string
period = '01/2011'
totdays = DateDiff("d", txtPeriod, DateAdd("m", 1, txtPeriod))
```

'this will give the totaldays of the month...

But i want to get total days of the previous month

User will type current month only, but code should validate previous month

Expected Output

```
If period = '02/2011' means then it should display 31 days 'January
If period = '03/2011' means then it should display 28 days 'February
```

How to do this...

Any Help

Comment: @JP 02/2011 only 28 days, 2012 only 29 days....

Comment: It's still January, I keep forgetting it's now 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine for me. Also, why do you have a variable `period`, but use `txtPeriod` in your calculations?

```
Dim dt As Date
Dim DaysInMonth As Integer

dt = CDate(txtPeriod.Text)
dt = DateAdd("m", -1, dt)
DaysInMonth = DateDiff("d", dt, DateAdd("m", 1, dt))
```